# knockout model table edit popup

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working on table layout page where the columns and rows will be populated dynamically, And the html is like

```
<h4>Select Columns:</h4>

<hr>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: gridOptions.columns">
            <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: gridData.data">
            <td data-bind="text: name "></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the knockout model will be something like

```
    var vm = {
    gridOptions: {
        columns: [{
            id: '1',
            name: 'Year',
        }, {
            id: '2',
            name: 'Month',
        }, {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Sun',
        }, {
            id: '4',
            name: 'Mon',
        }, ]

    },
    gridData: {
        data: [{
            id: '1',
            name: '2014',
        }, {
            id: '2',
            name: 'July',
        }, {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Study',
        }, {
            id: '4',
            name: 'Read',
        }, ]

    },
};


ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And I Want to create a model popup to edit the row in the tables.
Only the name in the row to edited and the for the column Sun,Mon the edit data is like ['Read', 'Sleep','Exam', 'Study']

How can I create a model popup to edit this and save them back db

Fiddle here : [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YKCb/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's a lot of development that you have to do here, but to try to point you in the right direction:

Have a modalData view model for the properties in your modal.
then, create a rowDblClick custom binding
use the jquery dblclick event handler for dblclicking on a row
use that valueAccessor to pass the observables from the row into the modalDataViewModel
something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.rowDblClick = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).dblclick(function(){
            vm.modalData(ko.mapping.fromJS(valueAccessor().id())); //if vm is your view model
        });
    }
}
```

then, you could have a save function in your view model that did an ajax call to send your modalData back to the server

```
self.saveRowData = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'your server url',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ self.modalData() });
}
```

I hope that's helpful, but again, you just have a lot of development to do.